# Boot Windows-10 live USB from GRUB

Tags: kali-linux, windows, live-usb, bootable

I've made a small mistake when trying to install Kali Linux on a smaller partition and erased my Windows 10 installation and I can't get back to my Win10 install.

I've made a bootable USB to try and get back onto Win10 using the below command:

```
sudo dd if=/root/Downloads/win10/win10.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=512k
```

and each time I restart and try to reboot from the USB I'm only welcomed by the GRUB menu.

I'm really new to using any Linux-based distribution. Would anyone let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: Usually you've to hit a key (F11?) on boot before grub stages from the harddrive to get the BIOS screen to select a boot device (ie. boot from USB Stick).

Comment: In Ubuntu and Debian [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can be installed and create a USB installer drive from a Windows iso file. mkusb works also in some Linux distros that are developed from Ubuntu and Debian, for example Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0):

By default your computer will (probably, depending on bios config) boot from the hard drive. When in the bios, you should see a line saying something along the lines of `press <key>  to enter boot menu`

If you do that, you should have the option of booting of the usb stick.

That said, this is only necessary if you screwed up the windows partition. If you only messed up installing grub, you can fix it without reinstalling windows.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern BIOS, you have usually two ways how to boot from a USB stick.

1. When the PC starts, you can open the BIOS settings and list the "boot" section. There you can set the USB disk as the first bootable medium. (Method depends on type of motherboard). Than save your settings and reboot.
2. During PC start you often see "Press F12 (or another key) to choose bootable medium." So do that and choose your usb stick.

First method saves settings forever, the second method does it only once. (If you restart the PC, you must do it again).

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot make a bootable Windows 10 installation/repair USB by just writing an official Windows 10 ISO onto an USB with `dd`.**

The ability for an ISO to be bootable when written to USB is not automatic: it requires that the ISO must have been specially prepared for it with the `isohybrid` process, or equivalent. Essentially, it means embedding hard-disk-like boot structures into the ISO image to supplement the "native" ISO9660 + El Torito boot structures. For whatever reason, Microsoft prefers not to do that.

The Microsoft-supported way to create an USB installation/repair media for Windows 10 is to use another computer with a working Windows OS to download and execute a Media Creation Tool, which will prepare the USB for you. If you have further questions on this matter, you should post them on [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/) instead, as this has nothing to do with Unix or Linux.

If you need to create a Windows USB installation media *on a Linux system*, [woeusb](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) might help you.